# RabbitMQ Server bundle distribution: Maven pom configuration

Tags: java, maven, rabbitmq

My requirement is, like, I have to download rabitmq-server for linux environment.

But, it will be downloaded, by my maven project, using maven-dependency-plugin.

So, I have to add the rabbitmq-server artifact details as a dependency, in my project POM.

**Therefore, my question is, Is it possible?
If yes, then what is the POM dependency config for that?**

Answer (score 0):

The maven artefact you'd need would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
    <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find many Maven dependencies on [MvnRepository](http://mvnrepository.com).

In order to use RabbitMq, you will have to download the server itself from the [RabbitMq website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html) and run the server, as described in their [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html).